# show a html with svg (map based ) in google maps at certain zoomlevel

Tags: google-maps, svg

Hi,
 I have integrated google maps in the web application

showing a marker until certain zoom level after that showing an info window

Can any one please guide me how to integrate svg map(html+svg content which is interactive) instead of info window.Tried with info window content as svg+html but could not succeed.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use the `zoom_changed` listener to listen to the event, and open and close the info as it is shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kylelam/xsL6dcLb/).

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
      if (map.getZoom()>5){ //if current zoom level greater than 5 then open infowindow,
                            //otherwise close it
          infowindow.open(map,marker);
      }else {
          infowindow.close();
      }
  });
```

Comment: Hello friend, Thanks for your input.  I have gone through the event listeners of google maps(minor task).The challenge here is to add html+svg into google maps and it should be interactive.I have gone through the custom overlays and had a sample html_svg into google maps . can you help me out with finding north east and south west latitudes and longitudes to place the html stuff??(its like a phase map of construction)

Comment: You mean the boundaries of the visible area?

Comment: yes kaho,  i could able to find the latitude and longitudes of the boundaries.Trying to make it interactive.Any help appreciated